# Vavg for a half wave rectifier

Tags: rectifier, voltage-measurement

I propose you this circuit which is used to convert the AC voltage of the sector into a filtered and not regulated voltage of about 4V.

[image]

From what I understood :
VC2 (AVG) = Vrect1(AVG)* R2+R3/(R1+R2+R3) so far ok, (then I find V1 it's simple).

But what I can't find (and yet I searched) is how to calculate the average value Vrect1(AVG) which should be equal to 109V (for Vsect = 311Vpeak) to validate what I find on the real circuit mounted and tested. However, we all know that the Vavg of a simple wave rectifier voltage = Vpeak/Pi=311/Pi=99V.

**How to calculate the real value of Vrect1 (which is equal to 109V AVG in the tested circuit). Thank you.**

Answer (score 4):

To calculate the average value of some function \$y=f(x)\$, we take the integral of the function, over some interval \$x_0\$ to \$x_1\$, and  divide by the width of the interval \$x_1-x_0\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_{AVG} &= \frac{1}{x_1-x_0}\int^{x_1}_{x=x_0}f(x)\cdot dx \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The full-wave rectified version of your mains voltage is simply a repeating sinusoid half-cycle, so we start with the average of a sinusoid in the interval 0 to π radians. If its amplitude is \$A\$, then the average will be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{FULL\_MEAN} &= \frac{1}{\pi-0}\int^\pi_{\theta=0}A\cdot sin(\theta)\cdot d\theta \\ \\
&= \frac{A}{\pi}\left[\vphantom{\frac{}{}}-cos(\theta)\right]^\pi_{\theta =0} \\ \\
&= \frac{A}{\pi}\left[1-(-1)\right] \\ \\
&= \frac{2A}{\pi} \\ \\
&= 0.637A \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The half-wave rectified signal will spend half its time at 63.7% average, and the other half at zero, so the average of a half-wave rectified sinusoid will be half of that:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{HALF\_MEAN} &= \frac{1}{2}V_{FULL\_MEAN} \\ \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{2A}{\pi} \\ \\
&= \frac{A}{\pi} \\ \\
&= 0.318A
\end{aligned}
$$

The half-wave rectified mains (220V  RMS, or 311V peak) will have an average of:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{MEAN} &= \frac{311}{\pi} \\ \\
&= 99V
\end{aligned}
$$

In practice the diode will remove 0.7V or so from the signal, so the actual measured average will be slightly less.

Answer (score 3):

> How to calculate the real value of Vrect1 (which is equal to 109V AVG
> in the tested circuit).

You can add a **.MEASURE** statement in LTspice to measure *average* over a time-span during the transient run. I have added TWO measure statements:

- the first cycle from the source (from 0 time to the 20 millisecond point.
- the last cycle, after the capacitor has fully charged (from 19.98 seconds to 20.00 seconds).

The results of the measured calculation shows up in the error_log, after a transient run:

```
.OP point found by inspection.

after_diode: AVG(v(vrect1))=98.97 FROM 0 TO 0.02
later_diode: AVG(v(vrect1))=110.412 FROM 19.98 TO 20
```

[image]